# Get method from Filter

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I'm using grails 2.4.4 and have a filter set up to filter requests on certain controllers. Is there a way to get the action/method that the request is for? I have a annotations on methods and I want to filter the requests to check and see if the method that the request is for has the annotation, I do some extra steps.

```
class MyTestFilters {

    def filters = {
        testFilter(controller:'myControler', action:'*') {
            before = {
                GrailsClass artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName('Controller', controllerName)
                def controller = applicationContext.getBean(artefact.clazz.name)

                Annotation annotation
                try{
                    annotation = controller.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(actionName, *SomeParameter*).getAnnotation(MyAnnotation)
                } catch(Exception e){
                    println e.getMessage()
                }
                if(annotation != null){
                    // Do some extra steps
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I have to look for a specific signature for the method. I don't really care about the parameters. All I want to know is if the method that the action is for, has my `MyAnnotation` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way to do it by iterating through all of the methods on the controller

```
Method[] methods = controller.class.getMethods().each { method ->
    if (method.name == actionName) {
        annotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation)
    }
}
```